# How to build a ship in the latest update (01.172 STABLE) of Space Engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

So I'm relatively new to Space Engineers but up until this point there has been a set of buttons on the bottom left of the "g" menu that allowed you to start building a ship, but today I started the game and the buttons aren't there and I can't seem to find them anywhere. I've googled the issue and couldn't find anything about this. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to start a ship or if I just have to start building on a landing gear that isn't locked down. I'm trying to build a small ship if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just place any block in space to start building a ship, or place it partially inside an asteroid to make it a station.

Placing landing gears as the first block has been glitchy for me, and doesn't connect to the block I place it on until I reload the world. I don't think this is intentional and might be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug. Take any block from the G menu and select it in the hotbar. You'll notice in front of you the block. You can slap it in space (where it'll drift if hit) or on an asteroid, planet or, of course, grid. Select it again while it's selected (easier done than said, NOT the other way round) to change block size.